# Javascript fill inputs on button click with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Everything almost works! i just need to find out why the code below won't give me more than the first buttons values.

```
public static function getProjectOnSearch($inp){
        return DB::table('projecten')
            ->select(DB::raw('titel,status,prioriteit,soort,projectnaam,projecturl
            ,gebruikersnaam,wachtwoord
            ,gebruiker_id,omschrijvingproject'))
            ->where('projectnaam', 'LIKE', '%'.$inp.'%')
            ->get();
    }
```

[image]I want to fill in some input fields with values from my database upon clicking an button. I have the code working to fill in an name and click on the search button to fill the inputs. That works great. When I use that code with the other button it won't work. see my code below.

Javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#wijzigKnop2").on("click",function(){
      var email2 = $('#zoeknaam2').val('');
      $('#titel2').val('');
      $('#status2').val('');
      $('#prioriteit2').val('');
      $('#type2').val('');
      $('#projectnaam2').val('');
      $('#projecturl2').val('');
      $('#gebruikersnaam2').val('');
      $('#wachtwoord2').val('');
      $('#omschrijving2').val('');

      $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/updateProjectData",
        data: {   input: email2 ,
               _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"
              }
      })
        .done(function( msg ) {
        $('#titel2').val(msg[0].titel);
        $('#status2').val(msg[0].status);
        $('#prioriteit2').val(msg[0].prioriteit);
        $('#soort2').val(msg[0].soort);
        $('#projectnaam2').val(msg[0].projectnaam);
        $('#projecturl2').val(msg[0].projecturl);
        $('#gebruikersnaam2').val(msg[0].gebruikersnaam);
        $('#wachtwoord2').val(msg[0].wachtwoord);
        $('#omschrijving2').val(msg[0].omschrijvingproject);
      });

    });
</script>
```

HTML Button with hidden input for value (normally the value would be typed in but this button will get the value from an HTML table which generates a row throught a foreach)

```
   <input type="hidden" value="{{$project->projectnaam}}" 
id="zoeknaam2" name="zoeknaam2" class="form-control" placeholder="Projectnaam">

<button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" id="wijzigKnop2" name="zoekProject" type="button">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
</button>
```

Any answers or ideas are very welcome thanks in advance for posting!

Comment: were your code get failed?

Comment: Please check your posted data is correctly passed to ajax.

Comment: I don't get any failures just nothing happens.. @ParthTrivedi how can i see   what is getting passed? does js have an sort dd($var) option?

Comment: Please look into your browser console to check the ajax output

Comment: F12 in your browser. check console > ajax request > request parameter

Comment: You have misspelled **title** here `$('#titel2').val(msg[0].titel);`. This is generating error.

Comment: Your code is broke down at data: {   input: email2 ,
               _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"
              }

Comment: Show your DB table names.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi no ajax request in my consoles.. and oh weird. i use the same code for the search input where I fill in the value myself and that still works

Comment: Is your ajax request not send?? then problem with data sended to ajax.

Comment: @FawadWarraich the code works when i use the other button and fill in the value for zoeknaam myself. but i copied the code and pasted it below that script to make it again where in the table the {{$project->projectnaam}} will be the value. and that won't work. only when i use the input myself.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi do you maybe see any solution for that? it's so weird it works with the same code when i fill in the value myself haha..

Comment: Have you check the value of `msg`? is it have something. check it in console.

Comment: $('#zoeknaam2').val() why are you setted to $('#zoeknaam2').val('') blank ?If you want to send value then only set var email2 = $('#zoeknaam2').val();

Comment: That one fixed it for the first button only! we are getting closer! @ParthTrivedi

Comment: Now what prob remaining? ajax side or server side code?

Comment: I think server. As all values are passed correctly to all different pencil buttons (check image provied in topic) but only clicking the first one changes the inputs. @ParthTrivedi

Comment: ok then you should track at server side only.

Comment: Okay what do you want to see into? @ParthTrivedi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97864/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-stefano-groenland).

Comment: Still not working.. php side now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check

```
var email2 = $('#zoeknaam2').val('');
```

this should be not blank

```
var email2 = $('#zoeknaam2').val();
```

If you get proper value in at server side then problem at server side code.

To check on response,do

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(msg));
```

As per questioner server side solving

```
public static function getProjectOnSearch($inp){
    return DB::table('projecten')         ->select(DB::raw('titel,status,prioriteit,soort,projectnaam,projecturl ,gebruikersnaam,wachtwoord ,gebruiker_id,omschrijvingproject')) ->where('projectnaam', 'LIKE', '%'.$inp.'%') ->get(); 
}
```

fixes all things.

Comment: helped a bit. need to fix my php code : public static function getProjectOnSearch($inp){
        return DB::table('projecten')
            ->select(DB::raw('titel,status,prioriteit,soort,projectnaam,projecturl
            ,gebruikersnaam,wachtwoord
            ,gebruiker_id,omschrijvingproject'))
            ->where('projectnaam', 'LIKE', '%'.$inp.'%')
            ->get();
    }

Comment: you need to search record by 'id' as you want it for edit purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of the element then clear it.

```
var email2 = $('#zoeknaam2').val();
$('#zoeknaam2').val('');
```